# Как исправить ошибку "IndexError: list index out of range" в коде?

Tags: python, python-3.x

В этой строчке `current, currentDistance = sorted(candidates, key = lambda x: x[1])[0]` выскочила ошибка, когда я хотел проверить путь в вершине B. Не могу понять, как её исправить.

```
nodes = ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H')
distances = {
    'A': {'B': 2, 'C': 1, 'D': 3, 'E': 9, 'F': 4},
    'B': {'C': 4, 'E': 3},
    'C': {'D': 8},
    'D': {'E': 7},
    'E': {'F': 5},
    'F': {'C': 2, 'G': 2, 'H': 2},
    'G': {'F': 1, 'H': 6},
    'H': {'F': 9, 'G': 8}}

print("Данный граф: ")
print(distances)

unvisited = {node: None for node in nodes}
visited = {}
print("Введите вершину:")
current = input()
currentDistance = 0
unvisited[current] = currentDistance

while True:
    for neighbour, distance in distances[current].items():
        if neighbour not in unvisited: continue
        newDistance = currentDistance + distance
        if unvisited[neighbour] is None or unvisited[neighbour] > newDistance:
            unvisited[neighbour] = newDistance
    visited[current] = currentDistance
    del unvisited[current]
    if not unvisited: break
    candidates = [node for node in unvisited.items() if node[1]]
    current, currentDistance = sorted(candidates, key = lambda x: x[1])[0]

print(visited)
```

Comment: `candidates` пуст

Comment: А как это исправить?

Comment: вообще, у меня этот код работает

Comment: Но дело скорее всего в том, что `if not unvisited: break` не сработала

Comment: У вас работает тогда, когда вы вводите любую вершину (у меня только на А работает)?

Comment: а, извиняюсь, я А и проверял

Comment: добавьте `if  not candidates: break` дело в том, при поиске вершины B, в конце остаётся только {'A': None}, что не пропускает проверка  if node[1]

Comment: Спасибо, все работает.